# Xcode's "branches" master is an incorrect project

Tags: xcode, github, version-control

I want to put my current project on GitHub, but within my Source Control Navigator, it shows Branches. After double clicking the Initial Commit within master, it's showing a different project than what is currently open on Xcode.

Eventually I want to put the Xcode project on GitHub, but even if I try, it puts whatever is in master, which is incorrect. How do I fix this?

**Edit:**
It took a few Terminal commands, and then I was able to go to the Source Control menu >> Commit without errors.

```
xcrun git config --global user.email you@whatever.com
xcrun git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

This put the correct version of the project on GitHub after I created a remove. Unfortunately, my master(current) is still incorrect and it includes that on GitHub for some reason.

Here are some screenshots of my Source Control Navigator. I only want first master displayed in the root folder or remote >> origin. Within the Branches folder, the only master shown is incorrect.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I moved a hidden ".git" (system) folder outside my main project folder. I then could create a new repository within the Source Control Navigator, create a new remote and the appropriate projects are visible in GitHub.